# How to increase on AWS CPU credit balance dropped to zero?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

CPU Credit balance on my AWS EC2 server dropped to zero and now my system is very slow.
What can I do to fix this?
I use t2.micro EC2 instance.

For how long it will be zero? To the end of month, forever?

Answer (score 4):

The credits will only come back if you reduce your CPU load. You can enable **T2 Unlimited** to avoid the limitation, but please note that extra costs will likely apply.

If you are frequently running out of Credits, you should consider using a larger instance type (eg `t2.small`, `t2.medium`) or a different instance family. T2/T3 instances are good for workloads that occasionally burst, but is not ideal for sustained workloads.

See: [CPU Credits and Baseline Performance for Burstable Performance Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html)